# Map dictionary to array to string

Tags: swift, higher-order-functions

I'm handling a dictionary which I need to parse into a string to create a property for a GraphQL mutation.
My dictionary is `[String: Bool]` and I need to extract the keys set to `true`.

```
let dict: [String: Bool] = ["Objct1": true, "Objct2": false, "Objct3": true]
```

Currently I'm using four functions (filter, enumerate, map and join) and, although I get the desired result, I wonder if I need all of them:

```
let string = dict.filter { $0.value }
    .enumerated()
    .map {
        return $0.offset == 0
            ? "\"\($0.element.key)\""
            : ", \"\($0.element.key)\""
    }
    .joined()
```

**Edit:**
The final string needs to be wrapped in `"`: `""Objct1", "Objct3""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a single `compactMap`, since first you'd need to `filter` your `Dictionary` to only keep the `true` values, then you'd need to `map` to return the `key` corresponding to the `true` values. However, you can always merge consequent `filter` and `map` calls into a single `compactMap`, since `compactMap` only keeps `non-nil` values, so instead of returning a boolean as you would for `filter`, in case your condition evaluates to true, you return whatever you would return in `map`, otherwise you return `nil`.

```
let trueKeys = dict.compactMap({key, value in value ? key : nil})
```

To join the keys into a single String, you can just call `joined` on the result of `compactMap`.

```
let graphQueryString = dict.compactMap({key, value in value ? "\"\(key)\"" : nil}).joined(separator: ",") // ""Objct3","Objct1""
```

Keep in mind that the ordering of your keys won't necessarily be the same as you declared the `Dictionary`, since `Dictionary` is an unordered collection by definition. If you want to keep ordering, you can use an array of tuples instead of a `Dictionary`, where the tuple will consist of the key-value pairs.

Comment: `{ $0.value ? $0.key : nil }` in the closure even, if you feel comfortable with it. I'll add that the order is not guaranteed (don't know if it was known by user, and/or specified).

Comment: `dict.compactMap { $1 ? $0 : nil }` :-)

Comment: @Larme you're right, the order isn't guaranteed, but that wasn't guaranteed with the original code either, since `Dictionary` is unordered by definition

Comment: @olejnjak even though I like conciseness usually, that piece of code sacrifices readability IMHO

Comment: Cool approach. The only minus is that I'm missing the \" \". Does it mean that i still need to use a `map`?